# PHP CURL causing Huge Apache access log

Tags: php, apache, logging, curl

I'm curious to know how to stop Apache from logging every URL I search with CURL.

My PHP script opens a few hundred thousand URLs, scans them, takes a tiny bit of info, closes, and then opens the next.

I discovered after opening the access log that each and every URL opened with CURL is written to the access log.

```
::1 - - [01/Dec/2010:18:37:37 -0600] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 8469 "-"..."
```

My access log is almost 45MBytes large. Help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your curl requests are coming from a single or otherwise manageable group of IPs you can exclude them from your logs with a configuration similar to the following:

```
# Set your address here, you can do this for multiple addresses
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "1\.1\.1\.1" mycurlrequest
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!mycurlrequest
```

You can do something similar with the user agent field which by default will indicate that it's curl.

You can read more here: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog (conditional logging is the last section under this header)
and here
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

If you want to conditionally exclude logging I would to it by the most precise method possible such as the ip address. In the event the server is externally accessible you probably don't want to find yourself NOT logging external requests from curl.

Using conditional logging you can also segment your logging if you want to multiple files one of which you could roll more frequently. The benefit of that is you can save space and at the same time have log data to help research and debug.

Comment: I'm assuming since I have access to the httpd.conf that these lines can just be pasted there?

Comment: yes they can go in either the main portion of the file or in a virtualhost directive.

Answer (score 3):

This is the purpose for access log - recording any incoming traffic

> In order to effectively manage a web server, it is necessary to get feedback about the activity and performance of the server as well as any problems that may be occurring. The Apache HTTP Server provides very comprehensive and flexible logging capabilities. This document describes how to configure its logging capabilities, and how to understand what the logs contain.

source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/logs.html

Of course, you have the option to disable logging (preferable not)

Comment: Hmm, well, this is on my localhost which no one else has access to. Is there any risk with disabling it?

Comment: @Chenelle - you can do anything you want ... let it run does not hurt.  Use log rotate if you know how to, otherwise, turn if off is perfectly alright.

Comment: @Chenelle No risk in turning it off.  If you notice your PHP script is not working as before, you can turn it back on. For instance, say the urls you're fetching are returning a 404 or 500.  Along with your Error log, it can help debug a problem. I would use log rotate as @ajreal has suggested. Best

Answer (score 0):

See the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog), about *Conditional Logs*.  That may be what you are looking for.